# mvc load view on culture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, uiculture

I don't seem to be able to find much on this. Is there a way I can have different views per culture? Is there something built in mvc3 for this? Is there anything out there about this? I don't want to use res files for whole pages, only for validation and such.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in functionality for this.

Look at this articles as start point:

- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization - Part 2 (NerdDinner)](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-part-2.aspx)

Also if you interested in database translation:

- [ASP.NET 2.0 Custom SQL Server ResourceProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14190/ASP-NET-2-0-Custom-SQL-Server-ResourceProvider)
- [ResourceProviderFactory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory.aspx)